# Create Page option missing from Site Actions menu

Tags: pages

We are having a weird issue on a couple of the portals in our SharePoint 2007 environment. The "Create Page" option from the Site Actions menu is no longer showing up. And when we manually go to the /_layouts/CreatePage.aspx page we see this error:

```
The site is not valid. The 'Pages' document library is missing.
```

However, the pages document library is still there. It has not been renamed which could cause this problem.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I supposed the rest of the site works okay? If you have Designer can you create a page with that? Just something to try.

Comment: Has the Publishing Web Feature been deactivated?

Comment: Publishing feature is activated both at the site collection and site level. Tried deactivating and reactivating both to no avail.

Comment: I have the same issue. I imported a publishing site and this error is occuring. Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Go to Site Settings, Site Collection features and verify that that the "Office SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure" feature is activated

Comment: Publishing feature is activated both at the site collection and site level. Tried deactivating and reactivating both to no avail.

Comment: If you go to View All Site Content -> Pages -> List Settings, does the list show the 'Page' content type as active? (You might have to click on the Advanced Settings/Allow Management of Content Types to see the content types)

Comment: Page content type is present and active as the default. All settings and columns seem normal.

Comment: Were these sites created off of a customized site definition by chance?  Also, are there any errors in your 12/LOGS about this?

Comment: Was the master page for the site / system master page changed at all?

Answer (score 0):

Check if your site collection is locked. This will not allow to create any pages. Use the below command to unlock.

stsadm -o setsitelock -url http://server_name -lock none

If not, check the below post, where its rectified using powershell - http://blogs.technet.com/b/stefan_gossner/archive/2011/09/15/common-error-the-site-is-not-valid-the-pages-document-library-is-missing-error.aspx

Comment: I tried both the stsadm command and the poweshell command. Both executed fine but did not fix the problem.